# GitHubのCODEOWNERS設定およびSlack連携について

Tags: github, slack

#### 現在のGitHub運用

- CODEOWNERSの設定によりmasterへのプルリクマージはコードオーナーの承認を必須にしている
- GitHubのSlack連携(`/github subscribe`)によりプルリク作成時にはレビュー者にメンションが飛ぶようにしている
- masterにプルリクをマージすると、GitHub Actionsにより本番デプロイされる、同様にdevelopmentにプルリクをマージするとステージングにデプロイされる

#### 困っていること

ステージング環境はエンジニアが自由にデプロイを行いたいが、developmentへのプルリクを作った際に自動的にコードオーナーがレビュアーに入ってしまい、その結果Slack通知がきて煩わしい

#### やりたいこと

developmentへのプルリクのレビュワーにはコードオーナーを入れない方法はありますでしょうか？
もしくは`/github subscribe`の設定で、reviewsの通知をするのを特定のブランチだけにできないでしょうか？
その他、通知がこないようにする方法がありますでしょうか？